# Triangle Side & Angle Classification Generator

Tags: java, random, integer, geometry, generator

My assignment consists of this: I have to design a calculator that allows user to enter the number of triangles. Goals are the following:

-User enters x number of triangles

-Computer automatically generates 3 numbers from my list of numbers between 3 and 13.

-Computer displays those numbers on screen.

-It decides if the numbers represent the sides of a valid triangle. (For example, 5, 5, and 13 do NOT create a triangle).

-If the numbers do not represent a valid triangle, displays an error message

-If the numbers are valid, the program determines, and displays

a) Side classification of the triangle – equilateral, isosceles, or scalene, and

b) The angle classification of the triangle – right, acute, or obtuse

[Here's what I did, but something seems to have gone wrong,as computer only displays "Acute", or "Not valid".]

public class triangle_creator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
private static int side1 = (int) (11 * Math.random() + 3);
private static int side2 = (int) (11 * Math.random() + 3);
private static int side3 = (int) (11 * Math.random() + 3);
private static int userNum; 
private static String userInput; 

private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    //get number of triangles by user in amountInput field 

    userInput=amountInput.getText(); 
    side1=Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    side2=Integer.parseInt(userInput); 
    side3=Integer.parseInt(userInput); 

    //add all sides together

    int sumTriangle= side1+ side2+ side3; 

   // generate error message 

    if(side1+ side2< side3){
        outputArea.setText("Not valid");
    }  
    else{
        if (side1==side2 && side1==side3 && side2==side3 )
            outputArea.setText("Equilateral"); 
        if (sumTriangle==sumTriangle) 
            outputArea.setText("Isosceles"); 
        if (side1!=side2&& side1!=side3&& side2!=side3)
            outputArea.setText("Scalene");

    if (side1*side1+ side2*side2==side3*side3){
        outputArea.setText("Triangle is right");
    }        

    else if (side3*side3< side1*side1+ side2*side2)   
        outputArea.setText("Triangle is acute");

    else if (side3*side3> side1*side1+ side2*side2){
        outputArea.setText("Triangle is obtuse");

    }

    else 
        outputArea.setText("Error");
```

}

I would really appreciate if you guys could give me at least one tip on how to make this work. Thaaanks!!! :)

Comment: Are you sure this code ever wrote "Not Valid"?

Comment: @Henry  Yes, only "Not Valid and "Triangle is acute". When I ran the program and entered the amount of triangles, and clicked on calculate, it only displayed one of those two words.

Comment: If you step through this with a debugger, you will see immediately why you're not getting the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `side1`, `side2` and `side3` are all set to the same value, namely the value returned by `Integer.parseInt(userInput)`.

In most cases, what will happen next is that `side1+ side2< side3` will be false, so the code enters the `else` block.  Now a whole lot of conditions are evaluated, and eventually, `side3*side3< side1*side1+ side2*side2` will be evaluated, and turns out to be true, so `"Triangle is acute"` is displayed.

But if you enter a large enough value in the field, you can get integer overflow when evaluating `side1+ side2< side3` - that is, `side1 + side2` might be too big to fit into an `int` field, so it will overflow to a negative value.  In that case, this condition will be true, `"Not valid"` will be displayed, and the `else` block will never be entered.